# Getting intermittent Compass Compile Errors using Codekit

Tags: compass-sass, codekit

I've asked Codekit's dev about this but he says it's likely a Compass issue, and I have no reason to doubt him. I've scoured the internet but haven't found a solution.
I keep getting intermittent errors when compiling my scss files, in multiple projects. Here's an example of the error, with the non-relevant file paths removed:

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

Errno::ENOENT on line 25 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/bin/../../scss/lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb: 
No such file or directory - /Users/shawn/.../content/themes/opt/.sass-cache/ef8bb231253aa8ba8f91c3886f9650b1e392f520/_bits.scssc
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

(This action was triggered by a change to _bits.scss)
```

I've tried deleting the .sass-cache folder, but the problem always reappears. I've also tried changing the names of my sass partials so that they include the full name (e.g. "_core.scss" instead of "core").
I don't really know how to manipulate compass from the command line, so I'm hoping someone can offer suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .scss (or appropriate file extension) to all your import calls. So far this has solved that problem for me.